# Help me understand apparent suspension for VLQ review-related automatic deletion comment

Tags: discussion, support, review-suspension

Today I received a review ban that states:

> You recently reviewed this post [low-quality-posts/24552082](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24552082). Although you correctly identified it as not being an answer, you chose to leave a comment. That did not help to solve the problem. You should have flagged it as "not an answer" so that it could be removed.

This post has since been removed by Cody Gray ♦ (I was the only vote on the VLQ review).

In the low-quality-post review I had selected the option: "Recommend Deletion". I did include the automatic comment from the selection box:

> Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review]

I do admit, there was one other comment on this question that was *not* the standard template, but did say something quite similar.

Otherwise, I don't understand how voting for deletion is the wrong response here -- was the ban for the similar to the existing comment? I don't think it would make sense to re-flag once it is in the VLQ review queue, and leaving the comment seems relatively harmless for a post that (we now know) was going to be deleted anyway.

I've been spending a lot of time going back over review results over the last week or two before this ban to understand the queues and especially how borderline cases work, but this one is a bit mysterious to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, shoot. This is [the second flag](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47815736#47815736) that I mishandled today. Sorry about that.

You did nothing wrong here. I've lifted your review suspension.

So…what happened? Well, when handling flags on obvious non-answers, I routinely go back and check the review history of said post, looking to make sure that all reviewers made the correct choice. In the case of a NAA, that "correct choice" would be to raise a NAA flag. Of course, that only pertains to those reviewers who saw the post in the "First Posts" or "Late Answers" review queues. If you saw it in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, then recommending deletion is *absolutely* the correct choice. I can only suppose that I misread the information in front of me. Nobody saw this post in "First Posts" or "Late Answers", which is somewhat unusual; usually a post goes through one or both of those review queues before it goes through "Low Quality Posts". But that's no excuse. I looked at your review choice, so seeing "Recommend Deletion" should have been the second check against my blunder. It wasn't. Dunno why. Sorry, again.

For those who track karma, I think I have been sufficiently punished. After handling some hundred flags on posts today, I stopped by the grocery store to purchase a few things. The fun started when I arrived back at my apartment complex and learned, to my dismay, that someone on the grounds maintenance crew thinks 8 PM is a reasonable time for the lawn sprinklers to come on. Slightly frustrating, but I found a workaround: walk through the flowerbeds on the opposite site. Yes, it's ironic that running the lawn-care system at an inopportune time incentivizes people to abuse the lawn. Anyway, I got to my apartment, stepped inside the door, and set down the bags of groceries that had been nestled in my arms. Then, I turned around again to go back to get the last few items. This time, on the way back from my car, the sprinklers outsmarted me: they had turned off on the side of the walkway for which they were previously on, and now they had turned on for the side of the walkway where I had previously walked through the flowerbed. So, no more walking through the flowerbed for me—at least, not if I wanted to avoid getting wet, which was kind of the whole point. There was to be no avoiding getting wet, since the sidewalk in the center was already flooded from the previous run of the sprinklers, the sprinkler heads were all spraying up in the air (instead of, you know, down towards the lawn), and all "safe" zones had been thoroughly eliminated.

I hope you enjoy your review privileges. Now, I need to go remove that mud from my carpet…

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, and I appreciate the detailed response.  No problem about the mistake, I've come to appreciate that at the scale of SO, mistakes will happen with the best of intentions.  I'll admit, moderation even at the 2k level takes a surprising amount of effort, I can only imagine what doing several hundred flag reviews on top of all your _real life_ must be like.  Good luck with the mud :(

Comment: I strongly oppose walking through flowerbeds ...

Comment: We don't actually have any flowers. They all turned blurry, so the groundskeepers replaced them with shrubs. @rene